# Cloning an input element and returning all the new inputs for them to be saved and sent through a GET request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I want to create a button that creates more "input" type tags and if I press submit, then these new inputs would be sent through the get request and I could also display all of them.

This is how far I've gotten:

**home.ejs**

```
<form action="/results" method="GET">
    <input id = "in" type="text" placeholder="Put stuff here" name="stuff">
    <button type ="button" onclick="myFunction();" name="button">
    Add
</button>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



<script>
    function myFunction(){
        let btn = document.getElementById("in");
        let b = btn.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(b); 
    }
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
app.get("/results",(req,res) =>{
    const api_key = "-----";
    let url = "https://------" + api_key;
    request(`${url}`,(err,resp,body)=>{
        if(!err & resp.statusCode==200){
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(body);

        }
    });
    console.log(req.query.stuff);
    res.render("home");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the cloned input element to `form` instead of throwing it into the `body`

```
<form action="/results" method="GET" id="formA">
    <input id = "in" type="text" placeholder="Put stuff here" name="stuff">
    <button type ="button" onclick="myFunction();" name="button">
    Add
</button>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        let btn = document.getElementById("in");
        let b = btn.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("formA").appendChild(b); 
    }
</script>
```